# Stratonovich Integral Proof (question)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

I understand almost all of the proof except for this one part.
I proceed to break up the Stratonovich sum as follows:

$$\begin{align} \displaystyle \sum B_{\frac{t_j+t_{j+1}}{2}}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{t_{j}}) &= \\ \sum [ B_{\frac{t_j+t_{j+1}}{2}}(B_{t_{j+1}}-B_{\frac{t_j+t_{j+1}}{2}})+B_{t_{j}}(B_{\frac{t_j+t_{j+1}}{2}}-B_{t_j})]+ \sum (B_{\frac{t_j+t_{j+1}}{2}}-B_{t_j})^2 \end{align}$$

In my book, it says, "Clearly, the first sum converges to $$\int^{T}_{0} B_t dB_t $$.

Why is this 'clear'?
I can sort of heuristically reason this result but it's not apparent to me why this is obvious? Is there a more rigorous way to see this?

Comment: Do you know the definition of the Itô integral?

Comment: Yes, I believe so! In my book it built up the definition from simple processes to general integrands.

Comment: I know there are a lot of ways to develop it, but do you have some theorem that implies "If $0 = t^m_0 < t^m_1 < \cdots < t^m_n =T$ is a sequence of partitions whose mesh tends to $0$ as $m\to \infty$, then $\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} B(t^m_i)\cdot (B(t^m_{i+1}) - B(t^m_i))$ converges in probability to $\int_0^T B_t\, dB_t$?" (it might specialize the partitions, but then we'd need to know something about the $t_i$ in your question)

Comment: Not quite stated as such but yes there is something similar to that.

Comment: Am i correct in understanding that each term of that first sum evaluates to half of the total, ie, each term as the mesh of the partition goes to 0 is $$\frac{W^2(T)}{4} - \frac{T}{4}$$ Hence their total sum gives the result. The reason being that the dB for each is exactly half of the standard definition while both are evaluated at their respective left endpoints?

Comment: I don't know why you're bothering to evaluate the integral.  If $\{t_i : 0\leq i \leq n\}$ is a partition of $[0,T]$, then so is $\{\frac12(t_{\lfloor i/2\rfloor}+t_{\lceil i/2\rceil}) : 0 \leq i \leq 2n\}$ and the mesh is half that of the former.  That's all that matters.  The sum you ran into is the ito sum with respect to this latter partition.

Comment: Well, I evaluated it just as a means to be concrete. If the mesh is half then it would make sense the integral should be half. Ok, thank you for your time!

Comment: It's a partition whose mesh is half that of another partition, and correspondingly the number of terms in the sum is doubled.  In the end, both sequences of partitions give sequences of Ito sums which converge in probability to the same stochastic integral.  I don't see where you're getting an extra half appearing.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. If say [0, T] = [0, 2] and t0=0< t1 = 1 < t2 = 2, then the sum I have above is essentially [B(0.5)(B(1)-B(0.5)) + B(1.5)(B(2)-B(1.5))] + [B(0)(B(0.5)-B(0)) + B(1)(B(1.5)-B(1))] and this converges to the same stochastic integral as the original, the only difference being (as you said) that since the mesh is halved, the number of terms is doubled.